# Distribute App Outside the Mac App Store

Tags: macos, xcode5, mac-app-store, code-signing-certificate

I'm a newbie in OSX Development. I built an application in which will be distributed outside the Mac App Store. I have all the other certificates and keys working except for the Developer ID (App and Installer) for production.

I know that this may sound stupid, but for what it's worth, I just wanna make sure.
Will my app still be considered Developer ID - signed if I exported it as a **Mac Installer Package** instead of selecting **Export Developer ID-signed Application**, when I install it to its destination devices? Will it be successfully installed or be rejected with GateKeeper-enabled devices?

[image]

I have been scratching my head for this since for some weird reason, I cannot add a new Distribution Developer-ID from the Dev Center. I was able to add a Developer ID earlier this week however, I ran into some issues with my private keys. As per suggested by Apple and many other developers, I revoked all the Developer IDs and private keys to start fresh. The problem now is that I can't add any new Developer ID (Distribution). I cannot add in both Dev Center and by requesting through Xcode 5.0.1. I'm stuck.

I have submitted a Bug Report to Apple, but who knows when they'll be able to resolve it.
So now, temporarily, since I don't have any choice (I guess), I'll use the Mac Installer Package, but the question is, will it work?

Any help would be very, very much appreciated.

Comment: I just found https://www.computerworld.com/article/3403011/wwdc-has-apple-closed-the-door-on-non-mac-app-store-apps.html right after adding the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

I've done this recently and have created a third Xcode project configuration to *Debug* and *Release* called *Archive*, which is a copy of *Release* except the app is signed using the *Mac App Distribution* / *Third Party Mac App Developer* and, confusingly there is a third name used for this same certificate.

I then changed the *Archive* scheme to use the *Archive* configuration to build.

Before doing this I had errors on some Macs when signing with my Developer ID, in some cases they claimed the app was corrupted, and in other cases I got gatekeeper blocking the app, forcing me to override it in `System Preferences > Security & Privacy`.

I personally use `xcodebuild` (from Jenkins) to build the app for distribution to testers, which I package in a `.dmg` so they only need to drag it to `/Applications` or `~/Applications` and I do all that using a script within the Jenkins configuration.  Your experience may differ to mine if you are using the Xcode app instead.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. Does the xcodebuild from Jenkins support OSX 10.9 with Xcode 5? Also, I'd like to know more about the code signing point of view on this.